# Java Websocket: Can Endpoint.onError be called during a send operation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I am trying to work out if javax.websocket.Endpoint.onError (and thus the resulting methods in say Spring) can be called during a call to any of the websocket send methods (e.g. javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint.Async.sendText or thin wrappers in say Spring), at least for the specific javax.websocket.Session, since if it can I need to make sure my server implementation regarding state associated with that socket is re-entrant, which complicates it.

The method is documented here:
https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html#onError%28javax.websocket.Session,%20java.lang.Throwable%29

It only mentions errors regarding incoming data. So I think it is safe to say the send will never itself cause it to be called (rather than passing an Exception to the send handler, or throwing an IOException from the basic remotes), but is incoming data processed while a send is in progress, and can that result in the method being called (presumably from another thread, threading details seem a bit thin as well...).